# Find element of order X using Chinese Reminder Theorem

Tags: group-theory, number-theory, finite-groups, chinese-remainder-theorem

For a school project I'm implementing [these Paillier performance improvements](https://eprint.iacr.org/2015/864.pdf).
In chapter **2.2 Scheme 3** subsection **Key Generation and Secure Choice of Parameters** there are remarks on how to efficiently generate parameter $\alpha$:

> The DSA key generation applied twice produces $g_1$ of order $\alpha_1$ in $\Bbb Z^∗_p$ and $g_2$ of order $\alpha_2$ in $\Bbb Z^∗_q$, respectively. As next step, we interpret $g_1$ and $g_2$ as elements in $\Bbb Z^∗_{p^2}$ and $\Bbb Z^∗_{q^2}$ , respectively. It is straight-forward to check whether the order of $g_1$ in $\Bbb Z^∗_{p^2}$ is $\alpha_1p$ and the order of $g_2$ in $\Bbb Z^∗_{q^2}$ is $\alpha_2q$ indeed. (In our experiments with the OpenSSL DSA key generation, this was always the case.) **One then finds $g$ of order $\alpha_1\alpha_2pq$ = $\alpha n$ in $\Bbb Z^∗_{p^2q^2}$ = $\Bbb Z^∗_{n^2}$ by using the Chinese Remainder Theorem.** As can be easily checked, α is indeed a divisor of λ.

(Please note that $n = p\times q$)

Variables I know values of (generated by DSA cryptosystem): $\{n, p, q, g_1, g_2, \alpha_1, \alpha_2\}$

So far I understand that:

"$g_1$ of order $\alpha_1$ in $\Bbb Z^∗_p$" $\implies g_1^{\alpha_1} \equiv 1 \pmod p$

"$g_2$ of order $\alpha_2$ in $\Bbb Z^∗_q$" $\implies g_2^{\alpha_2} \equiv 1 \pmod q$

Following the text:

"$g_1$ of order $\alpha_1p$ in $\Bbb Z^∗_{p^2}$" $\implies g_1^{\alpha_1p} \equiv 1 \pmod {p^2}$

"$g_2$ of order $\alpha_2q$ in $\Bbb Z^∗_{q^2}$" $\implies g_2^{\alpha_2q} \equiv 1 \pmod {q^2}$

The task is:

> Find $g$ of order $\alpha_1\alpha_2pq$ = $\alpha n$ in $\Bbb Z^∗_{p^2q^2}$ = $\Bbb Z^∗_{n^2}$ by using the Chinese Remainder Theorem.

How can I reorganise those equations to compute $g$ using CRT? Or should I approach to the problem differently?

Thank you,
Muzosh.

Comment: You’ll need, I believe, $\alpha_1p$ and $\alpha_2q$ relatively prime.

Comment: If you have that, then you just need to solve $$g\equiv g_1\pmod{p^2}\\g\equiv g_2\pmod{q^2}$$

Comment: This works! Thank you.

Comment: Would you or someone else please try to explain, why that is? Although, it is not necessary for my project progress.

Comment: If $g$ has order $a$ modulo $m,$ and $g$ has order $b$ modulo $n,$ and $\gcd(m,n)=1,$ then $g$ has order $\operatorname{lcm}(a,b)$ modulo $mn.$